# Setting a String Equal to a Method

Tags: java

I am **very** new to Java and am in a Java intro class so I apologize if this question is offensively simple but I am wondering if it is possible to set a string equal to a method.  I guess I already know the answer is no because Netbeans is throwing an error but I just don't know another way to program this question:

"Create a new string called passwd formed by concatenating every alternate non-space character in sentence (*'sentence' is a string she had us create earlier in the assignment*) starting with the first. To do this, you need to a loop to go through the string sentence and retrieve characters from alternate index positions. If the extracted alternate character is NOT a space, then add it to the new String. Do not include spaces."

With my limited Java knowledge all I can think to do is to set a new string equal to a "for" method, but apparently this isn't allowed.  How would I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: if you have some code, paste it to find fast and accurate answer:)

Comment: Please read a standard Java tutorial. Didn't you get any material from your teacher? Such as a book recommendation?

Comment: Like I said, I tried setting a string equal to a for method.  I think my problem is just not fully understanding Java.  This is the first assignment we've had so I've read a lot of stuff it's just this is the first time we've actually started coding (please tell me it seems a little difficult for a first program).  I just don't really understand all the vocabulary and syntax.  I think it's just a matter of practice and I started doing www.codeyear.com as recommended by a friend.  I'll practice with this and I'll eventually get it.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you are required, you will need to initialize the string to the sentence you want to process, the, loop for the length of the string using the [.charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method and see if the Character is a space. To do this, you can use the [Character.isWhiteSpace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhiteSpaceChar%28char%29). If the character is not a space, you can append it to a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: just fyi isSpace returns true for tab, line separator as well and not sure if OP really wants that. Moreover `isSpace()` is deprecated and has been replaced by `isWhiteSpace()` now.

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for letting me know. Answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (assuming string is your original string):

```
StringBuffer passwd = new StringBuffer();
for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i+=2) {
    if (string.charAt(i) != ' ')
        passwd.append(string.charAt(i));
}
System.out.printf("passwd is: [%s]%n", passwd.toString());
```

Comment: @vulkanino: Pls read the OP's question one more time. This is from the question `go through the string sentence and retrieve characters from alternate index positions`

Comment: you're right, I didn't get the "alternate" meaning in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

In the assignment text there's everything you need to do. Even if you don't know Java, you can write down an informal algorthim:

1. Declare and initialize a new string, possibly the same size of the source string. In Java you could use a StringBuffer to speed up the copy
2. Cycle for each char in the source string.In Java you have charAt().
3. Is it a space? If yes, then continue the loop. I Java you have isSpace().
4. If it is not a space, then append this char to the new string. In Java you have the append method of a String or a StringBuffer

Answer (score 0):

Even if it would be possible to somehow set a string equal to a "for" method (actually `for` is a statement, not a method), what would the string contain then? "For"? That's certainly not what you want.

> you need to a loop to go through the string sentence

So create a (for) loop.

> retrieve characters from alternate index positions

See [String.charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

> If the extracted alternate character is NOT a space, then add it to the new String.

Learn how `if` works. [Character.isWhitespace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) method might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String result() {
  String result = "";
  for (char c : log.toCharArray()) {
    if (!" ".equals(c)) {
      result += c;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take _alternate_ non-space characters, plus it's probably better to use a StringBuilder rather than appending to the String every time.